How to Create Win32 API Menu Items with Icons?
I am trying to add an icon to a menu item in a Windows application using the Win32 API, but the icon is not showing up. I have followed the instructions from the Win32 API documentation, but it's still not working. Can anyone help me fix this issue?
HMENU createContextMenu(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    if (hMenu) {
        AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_APP_ABOUT, "&About");
        AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, (UINT_PTR)-1, NULL);
        AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_APP_EXIT, "&Exit");

        // Assuming you have an icon resource named ICON_MENU_EXIT
        HICON hIconExit = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_MENU_EXIT));
        if (hIconExit) {
            MENUITEMINFO menuItemInfo = { sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) };
            menuItemInfo.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP;
            menuItemInfo.hbmpItem = (HBITMAP)CopyImage(hIconExit, IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_COPYFROMRESOURCE);
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, IDM_APP_EXIT, FALSE, &menuItemInfo);
            DestroyIcon(hIconExit); // Destroy the icon only if setting the image was successful
        }
    }
    return hMenu;
}

case WM_USER_TRAYICON:
        if (lParam == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK) {
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        } else if (lParam == WM_RBUTTONUP) {
            POINT trayPos;
            GetCursorPos(&trayPos);
            HMENU hMenu = createContextMenu(hwnd,hInstance);
            SetForegroundWindow(hwnd); // Menjamin menu bekerja dengan benar
            UINT clicked = TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_NONOTIFY, trayPos.x, trayPos.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
            if (clicked == IDM_APP_EXIT) {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
            DestroyMenu(hMenu); // Hancurkan menu setelah digunakan
        }
        break;

I have tried to load the icon from a resource using LoadIcon function and set it to the menu item using SetMenuItemInfo or SetMenuItemBitmaps.
I expected the icon to appear next to the menu item 'Exit' when the menu is displayed.
However, despite following the steps outlined in the Win32 API documentation, the icon is still not showing up.

You're observing the return value from LoadIcon(), but then suddenly take no interest in what SetMenuItemInfo() returns. This isn't prudent.

An HICON and an HBITMAP are completely different types.  You can't use HICON directly with SetMenuItemInfo() or SetMenuItemBitmaps().
You will have to either:

change your resource type to BITMAP, and then use LoadBitmap() or LoadImage(IMAGE_BITMAP) to load it as an HBITMAP.

stay with an ICON resource, load it as an HICON as you are, and then either:
a. copy it to a separate HBITMAP that you can then assign to your menu item. See How to convert HICON to HBITMAP in VC++?
b. Owner-draw the menu item, handling the WM_DRAWITEM message, so you can draw your HICON onto the HDC of the menu using DrawIcon().



Don't you need PARGB32 bitmaps for transparency?

If you want (per-pixel) alpha transparency you need a 32bpp bitmap (V5) as the source and pass the LR_CREATEDIBSECTION flag to LoadImage().

HMENU createContextMenu(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hInstance) {
HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
if (hMenu) {
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_APP_ABOUT, "&About");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, (UINT_PTR)-1, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_APP_EXIT, "&Exit");

    HICON hMenuExitIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_MENU_EXIT));
    if (hMenuExitIcon) {
        // Create a compatible DC
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

        // Get the size of the icon
        ICONINFO iconInfo;
        GetIconInfo(hMenuExitIcon, &iconInfo);
        BITMAP bmp;
        GetObject(iconInfo.hbmColor, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

        // Create a bitmap compatible with the DC
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight);

        // Select the bitmap into the memory DC
        HBITMAP hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

        // Draw the icon onto the bitmap
        DrawIconEx(hdcMem, 0, 0, hMenuExitIcon, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);

        // Set the bitmap as the item's bitmap
        MENUITEMINFO menuItemInfo = { sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) };
        menuItemInfo.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP;
        menuItemInfo.hbmpItem = hBitmap;
        SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, IDM_APP_EXIT, FALSE, &menuItemInfo);

        // Clean up
        SelectObject(hdcMem, hOldBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        DestroyIcon(hMenuExitIcon);
    } else {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to load icon for exit menu item.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
return hMenu;

Now it's working

These are old, confusing APIs, and my memory is fuzzy, but I think there are a couple things going on.

If you want the icon next to the string, then you want MIIM_CHECKMARKS and to set the hbmpChecked and hbmpUnchecked fields.  When you use MIIM_BITMAP, that's saying you want an icon instead of the string.

You need to use actual bitmaps, not icons.  (There are places in the WinAPI where bitmaps, icons, and cursors can be used somewhat interchangeably, but I don't think this is one of them.)


Until you get it working, I'd suggest stepping through this code in a debugger and checking all of the return values.

When switching from icons to bitmaps, you'll want transparent sections that show the color of the menu.

The old way to do this was to use 8-or-less-bit color bitmaps and to load them with LoadImage (using LR_LOADTRANSPARENT and probably LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS) not LoadIcon.  The remaps the "background" color in the bitmap with color scheme's choice for a 3D surface, which is typically the same as the background color of the menu.

As other answers have shown, you can instead use 32-bit color bitmaps with an alpha channel.  Kids these days have it so easy.



"For the bitmaps to have "transparent" sections that show the color of the menu, you need to use 8-bit color bitmaps" - I'm sure this used to be true at some time, decades ago. Ever since the bitmap file format introduced support for a dedicated alpha channel there's no reason to fake transparency using the LR_LOADTRANSPARENT flag. Just use a true 32bpp ARGB bitmap (as illustrated in this answer).

@IInspectable:  Interesting.  I know toolbars work with alpha channels, but I didn't know (or had forgotten) the stock menus were updated with that capability.
